# Auto check hierarchy data in SSRS parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I don't think this is possible, but it's worth a try. Is there a way to auto check hierarchy data in report parameters?

For example:
Parameter = Locations

```
Location A
 -Location aa
 -Location ab
Location B
 -Location ba
 -Location bb
```

Right now I have it setup so each location and sub location is a sepreate checkbox (6 checkboxes in total here). Is it possible to check location A and have aa and ab auto check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible through the SSRS parameter interface, except maybe with some heavy unsupported Javascript coding.

If you really need this behavior you'd be better off building your own front-end/wrapper for the report.